# Cannot delete bot message in telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I sent a message using telegram bot api. The bot I'm writing is kind of private channel bot, not inline.

So I've just sent a message, 48 hours has not lasted.

I tried to use this: https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/deleteMessage?chat_id=CID&message_id=MID

As a result I got `"Bad Request: message can't be deleted"`

Why so?

In my case I'm asking user for a price. If the price is not valid, I send a notification, asking user to re-enter the price. So, there might be many service messages, asking user to correct the price. After he entered correct value I want to erase these service messages. I can't think of any other solution except removing these messages, but I couldn't manage to do this.

Comment: Which type of message you are try to delete?

Comment: Just a message which I've sent manually using my bot? Like a service message: "Hey, your price is not valid, try again"